# Is there any api gateway which allows middle ware integration for kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, reverse-proxy

I want to develop a custom API gateway for kubernetes to support user-based routing to canary release. I haven't found even any API gateway which serves this purpose.

Comment: You mean to route to specific service/pod based on which user is accessing your resource ? Could you be a bit more specific in your requirement and your existing setup.

Comment: @Anoop Take this scenario, I have kubernetes cluster and I am releasing based on Canary release concept and I want only limited known users to reach that service. So I need a custom routing mechanism on the API gateway level.

Comment: How about having a nginx pod(with its associated service) as API gateway tier and define your custom routing logic there and route to different services from there ?

Comment: Will ngnix allow me to open the request header and how I can define custom routing logic? Any sample?

Comment: what specifically you mean by custom routing logic ? I mentioned nginx just as an example .. you could use any reverse proxy server for this.

Comment: You might want to try [kong](https://konghq.com/kong/) which is also based on nginx , but much more easier to configure since it provides rest apis and also comes with some open source UI dashboards to allow you do these configurations. Kong has concept of consumers which you can leverage to route your users to specific backend url using its access control plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Istio Service Mesh allows you to do just that.
You can route users to different application versions by creating routing rules based on custom headers, cookies, etc...

If there's no specific rules, you can expose services with different weights (i.e 90% - 10%).

Of course it's installable on top of Kuberenetes and replaces the ingress controller.

Hope this helps.